# 12.04 - clean installation failed on APT configuration failure

Tags: installation, 12.04

I tried to install Ubuntu 12.04 on the partition where I had Ubuntu 10.10, by first formating the partition (ext4) and keeping the same partition settings (the mount point is '/').

I use the Ubuntu installation disk I made on a USB drive.

Installation went fine until an error indicating a failure in APT configuration from the CD .

And now the system isn't bootable anymore :

```
Grub error, file not found
```

What can I do ?

Comment: Are u sure during installation, u selected the internal drive instead of usb? I think the installer wrote grub menu on the usb.

Comment: see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Comment: In fact there was another error window saying "low disk space" that may be linked to the apt configuration failure.

Comment: I followed the instruction on http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows to reinstall the grub menu (I think that it wasn't install due to the APT error but my ubuntu partition doesn't boot). The grub error wasn't the most important problem, the real problem is the APT installation failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using discussions on a French forum, I could determine (no real proof or explanation) that you cannot install Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits using a start disk made on Ubuntu 10.10 32 bits.

I solved the main problem by making another start disk, this time from a Ubuntu 11.04 (32 bits) computer.

Another thing I got (from here, thanks beeju who gave the link) is that if your grub menu isn't working (due to a bad installation point or a crash at the bad time) you can reinstall it without problems : [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)